# How to not duplicate the element on removal of Multi-Select Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Good day everyone,

Given the following JSfiddle snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/abUF2/

How would it be possible to not copy back the elements from the right side to the left side when removing them from the right side (i.e. just making them disappear instead of copy back)?

Thank you very much for your help.

```js
var  received = false; 

$("ul").on('mousedown', 'li', function (e) {
           
            if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) ) {
                if ($(this).next('li').hasClass('pholder'))
                    $(this).next('li').remove();
                else
                    $(this).after($(this).clone().addClass('pholder').hide());
            }
            else{
            if ($(this).next('li').hasClass('pholder')) { }
            else                $(this).after($(this).clone().addClass('pholder').removeClass('ui-selected').hide());
            }
        });

$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
}).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    delay: 150, //Needed to prevent accidental drag when trying to select
    revert: 0,
    helper: function (e, item) {
        //Basically, if you grab an unhighlighted item to drag, it will deselect (unhighlight) everything else
        if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
            item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //HERE'S HOW TO PASS THE SELECTED ITEMS TO THE `stop()` FUNCTION:
        
        //Clone the selected items into an array
        var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
        
        //Add a property to `item` called 'multidrag` that contains the 
        //  selected items, then remove the selected items from the source list
        item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
        
        //Now the selected items exist in memory, attached to the `item`,
        //  so we can access them later when we get to the `stop()` callback
        
        //Create the helper
        var helper = $('<li/>');
        return helper.append(elements);
    },
     start: function (event, ui) {
                       $('.pholder').show();
                },
    receive: function (event, ui) {
                    received = true;
                },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        
          if (!received) {                    
                        $('.pholder').remove();
                    }
                    else {
                        received = false;
                        $('.pholder').removeClass('pholder');
                    }
        
        //Now we access those items that we stored in `item`s data!
        var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');
        
        //`elements` now contains the originally selected items from the source list (the dragged items)!!
        
        //Finally I insert the selected items after the `item`, then remove the `item`, since 
        //  item is a duplicate of one of the selected items.
        ui.item.after(elements).remove();
    }

});
```

```css
ul {
    border:1px solid Black;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top
}
li {
    background-color:Azure;
    border-bottom:1px dotted Gray
}
li.selected {
    background-color:GoldenRod
}
```

```html
    <p>Multi-select Drag</p>
    <p>
        <kbd>Click</kbd> to select individual items<br />
        <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> to select multiple items
    </p>
    <br />

    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `.pholder`? When I comment out the `mousedown` stuff at the start (where `.pholder` gets created), everything seems to work correctly.

Comment: I need to duplicate the left column, although when I remove them from the right I need them to "delete" themselves not duplicate again on the left.
Example: Pull 1 to right side, when pulling one out of right side it disappear and not copy another 1 on the left.

Also, when pulled out of the left side, the number need to stay available for another pull as it is a 1 to many ( right to left ) type relation.